# How to pass huge number of data one page to another page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm working with ASP.net MVC4 application. I'm new for MVC, So let me know how to pass huge number of data from one page to another. I got the data from service, Data has HTML content, So i need to pass this date to another page(different controller).

Comment: without your code it is hard to help you, but the whole purpose of MVC is to remove this stateless situation of data. but nonetheless as everypage will be having their own controller, then it is easy to reload the data from the server. If you are looking for something similar to ascx controls, then you can easily use partial view. But please give us examples of what you are trying to do with code. Voting down because no code is provided.

Comment: You need to be more specific about your need. The answer will depends on that. Why do you want to pass data between one page to another at first place?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/576514/AplusBeginner-splusTutorialplusonplusVariousplus

Answer (score 0):

You can Use `Session`

```
Session["MyKey"]=Your_Data;


if(Session["MyKey"]!=null)
{
//retrieve From Session

Your_data=  Session["MyKey"];

}
```